# Getting last day of previous quarter

Tags: sql, date, hive, calendar, hiveql

When I run

```sql
SELECT
  MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE())-1 QUARTER - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

[here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_makedate), it works as intended. However, in Hive I get an error that I'm missing a closing parenthesis. My query is:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, t2.programme
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT programme FROM table2
        WHERE yyyy_mm_dd = MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE())-1 QUARTER - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    ) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id AND t2.yyyy_mm_dd = t1.yyyy_mm_dd
```

What have I done wrong?

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:75 missing ) at 'QUARTER' near 'QUARTER' l

We are using Hive v1.1.0.

Comment: Can you describe what this does: MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE())-1 QUARTER - INTERVAL 1 DAY

Comment: @leftjoin it gets the last day of the most recent quarter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to do in a number of ways. Two methods:

```
select last_day(printf('%04d-%02d-%02d',year(current_date),(month(current_date)-1) div 3 * 3 ,1));
```

Returns:

```
2019-03-31
```

One more method:

```
select last_day(concat(year(current_date),'-',lpad((month(current_date)-1) div 3 * 3,2,0) ,'-01'))
```

**Important versions note:** In older versions of Hive `current_date` may not work, use `unix_timestamp()` instead:

```
select last_day(concat(year(current_timestamp()),'-',lpad((month(current_timestamp())-1) div 3 * 3,2,0) ,'-01'))
```

Read [**manual**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) and invent your own method.

Comment: Works perfectly. Now I have a second problem. If I do `WHERE yyyy_mm_dd = select last_day(printf('%04d-%02d-%02d'...`, then my `ON` join condition will always be 2019/03/31. I need to select programme from p form the previous last day of the quarter and then join on the full set of `p.yyyy_mm_dd`. Thanks for the help. @leftjoin

Answer (score 1):

Hive does not have the same syntax and functions as MySQL.

[Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) is a list of all date function supported by Hive.

Using these functions, your SELECT query translates to:

```
SELECT
  date_add(add_months(trunc(date()), (extract(quarter from date()) -1 ) * 3)), -1)
```

Comment: This gives mismatched input 'QUARTER' expecting ) near 'INTERVAL' in expression specification. Same result if I put the first `(` before the `yyyy_mm_dd` in the where clause.

Comment: Ok, but it still gives you a hint that the syntax is not correct. You tried the SELECT query in MySQL. Hive does not have the same syntax as MySQL in every regard. I will change the answer in that regard.

Comment: @Someguywhocodes Adapted the answer to use actual Hive syntax.

Comment: it looks like we are using hive v1.1.0, which doesn't support `quarter`. Is there any workaround to do the same, without `quarter`? I will update my original Q

Comment: @Someguywhocodes Sure, just do  quarter = ((month -1) / 3) +1.